# omegaconf errors. validation error line 896

Tags: omegaconf

I am total beginner so be easy on me. I got `Retrieval-based-Voice-Conversion-WebUI` when I try to run it on my mac I get the following message:

```
file "/library/frameworks/python.framework/versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-
packages/omegaconf/omegaconf.py", line 896, in _create_impl raise 
validationerror( omegaconf.errors.validationerror: object of unsupported 
type: '_missing_type' full_key: object_type=none
```

- Any idea how to fix this?
- Uninstall and install the omegaconf

Comment: Please add a minimal example reproducing your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example